# What's a good way to create a multiselect US state field

Tags: django, class, many-to-many

I'm looking to create a multi-select US state field.

One way to do it is to create a Model and then use a `ManyToManyField` on another Model. See my example below:

```
class States(models.Model):
   ALABAMA= 1
   ALABAMA= 2
   ARIZONA= 3
   GEO_CHOICES = (
       (ALABAMA, 'alabama'),
       (ALABAMA, 'alaska'),
       (ARIZONA, 'arizona'),
   )

   id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=GEO_CHOICES, primary_key=True)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.get_id_display()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user ...
    state = models.ManyToManyField(States)
```

**Question 1:**
Is there a way that I can include the 2 digit short code in my code below?

**Question 2:**
Is there a default state list? What about zip codes our state counties?

Comment: What do you mean with your first question: `Is there a way that I can include the 2 digit short code in my code below?` Where in your code do you want to include it?

Comment: State Abbreviations - AL - alabama, TX - Texas, UT - Utah. I'm guessing it'd be a field in a class. So I could do something like states.id, states.name, states.code to get either 1,Alabama or AL respectively. I'll look into django-localflavor that you mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding you first question:

> Is there a way that I can include the 2 digit short code in my code below?

It is just like you already said in a comment: you should probably create a model `State` with all the info like code and abbreviation.

But look at the packages I linked below, maybe they are helpful in your quest.

---

As to your second question:

> Is there a default state list? What about zip codes our state counties?

You could look into:

1. the official [django-localflavor](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor) repo.
2. this 6-year-old repo [django-localflavor-us](https://github.com/myusuf3/django-localflavor-us) very similar to the previous one I mentioned.